# HP WIFI problems

Tags: wireless

I have a HP Pavilion DV6500. I installed Ubunyu today and cant seem to get it to connect to WIFI. It has a switch on the front to turn on/off wireless and no matter which way I push saod switch, it stays off. Is there a way to fix this or...

Answer (score 0):

HP Pavilion DV6500 regularly ships the Broadcom 4311 chipset. Install the file "linux-firmware-nonfree"

Please run via cable connection:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

or use the Software-Center instead. You may want to reboot.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Can you please add more detail to your answer, such as how to install the package?